# Keycloak and Vault Integration with Client Role

Tags: keycloak, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to integrate Keycloak with Vault. I have 2 Vault policies (Admin, Dev). I want to use a path 'keycloak', and have done `$ vault auth enable -path=keycloak oidc`.

The problem I want to solve, is to map Vault Policy with the Keycloak Client Role.

```
$ vault write auth/keycloak/config \
  oidc_discovery_url="https://$KEYCLOAK_ADDRESS/auth/realms/master" \
  oidc_client_id="vault" \
  oidc_client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET} \
  default_role="admin" type="oidc"

$ vault write auth/keycloak/role/admin \
    bound_audiences="vault" \
    allowed_redirect_uris="https://$VAULT_ADDRESS/ui/vault/auth/oidc/oidc/callback" \
    allowed_redirect_uris="https://localhost:8250/oidc/callback" \
    user_claim="sub" \
    policies="admin" \
    ttl=4h \
    role_type="oidc" \
    oidc_scopes="openid"

$ vault write auth/keycloak/role/dev \
    bound_audiences="vault" \
    allowed_redirect_uris="https://$VAULT_ADDRESS/ui/vault/auth/oidc/oidc/callback" \
    allowed_redirect_uris="https://localhost:8250/oidc/callback" \
    user_claim="sub" \
    policies="dev" \
    ttl=4h \
    role_type="oidc" \
    oidc_scopes="openid"
```

I want admin and dev roles in Vault bound to "vault" client in Keycloak. However, according to the group that the user is bounded to, I want the user to have different policy. (Both login via console with `vault login -method=oidc keycloak`)

Have any ideas? The solution I have in mind is to make 2 different client. However, I want only 1 client 'vault'. Can this be achieved?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @DanGarthwaite Not yet, unfortunately.

Comment: groups_claim=groups

Answer (score 1):

Go to your client, then go to Mappers tab, then press Add Builtin
[image: Add Builtin]

Then find groups in search and add it
[image]

After this in your jwt token payload will appear groups section

Then configure groups_claim in your vault oidc configuration

```
$ vault write auth/keycloak/role/admin \
bound_audiences="vault" \
allowed_redirect_uris="https://$VAULT_ADDRESS/ui/vault/auth/oidc/oidc/callback" \
allowed_redirect_uris="https://localhost:8250/oidc/callback" \
user_claim="sub" \
policies="admin" \
ttl=4h \
role_type="oidc" \
oidc_scopes="openid" \
groups_claim="groups"

$ vault write auth/keycloak/role/dev \
bound_audiences="vault" \
allowed_redirect_uris="https://$VAULT_ADDRESS/ui/vault/auth/oidc/oidc/callback" \
allowed_redirect_uris="https://localhost:8250/oidc/callback" \
user_claim="sub" \
policies="dev" \
ttl=4h \
role_type="oidc" \
oidc_scopes="openid" \
groups_claim="groups"
```